NestJS Compile warnings
I'm trying to learn NestJS and I'm having issues with this code below. @nestJS warning says ""nestjs": Unknown word.cSpell"
For the functions like status and send I'm getting the following warning: "Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.t"
So far looks like it's not failing my tests or stopping my application from running but I'm worried about why this is showing an error/warning.


make sure you have @types/express installed as a dev dependency. I just tested that code here and got no errors
btw this has nothing to do with Nestjs at all, it's just typescript stuff.

Thanks for the reply! I just installed this dependency. Still seeing the warnings though even after a reboot.  But same errors are showing even though the tests are passing fine and running it seems to be fine as well.

ins't this just a VSC thing? I mean, did you get any error on building the typescript project?

I didn't get any errors building the typescript project. So I guess it is just a VSC thing?

could be. In this case, make sure that your editor is using the same tsc as the one available for your project at node_modules. You can do that via command palette: > typescript: select typescript version
